# In AngularJS why am I unable to assign an array in the callback of a resource promise to the scope in a controller?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Given what appears to be the same Resource object, seen below, produced by two different paths, for some reason the behavior of those objects is inconsistent--in one case I can successfully retrieve the array ['values-response']['distinct-value'] and in the other case I get "undefined" instead when I try.

Provided the following written to the console after using the `then()` method on a promise returned by `$q.all()` in a service:

```
Resource
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
values-response: Object
>  distinct-value: Array[64]
metrics: Object
name: "term"
type: "xs:string"
```

Why can't I assign the distinct-value array to the scope to be used in `ng-repeat`? Before changing my code to use a promise, I was able to do that in the callback of a `$resource` `get()` method:

```
$scope.topics = data['values-response']['distinct-value'];
```

Then I could use `data-ng-repeat="topic in topics"` in the template's `ng-repeat`.

**However**, since switching to a promise, if I try doing this:

```
$scope.topics = data.topics['values-response']['distinct-value'];
```

then the console returns "undefined", although it appears to be resolved, according to the output above.

Instead, I am required to do:

```
$scope.topics = data.topics;
```

Then access the array in `ng-repeat` as shown below, which I am not sure is optimized:

```
<button data-ng-repeat="topic in topics['values-response']['distinct-value'] | filter:textFilter | orderBy:browseOrder:browseDirection as resultsTopics" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
```

JSON is returned by a MarkLogic REST API. I don't think it should be necessary, but just in case I experimented with `angular.fromJson()` to no avail.

More complete picture of the code, using simplified snippets follows:

```
app.factory('BrowseService', [
  '$q', '$resource',
  function($q, $resource) {
    var r = $resource('http://localhost\\:8005/LATEST/values/:facet', {
      format: 'json',
      options: 'browse'
    });
    var p1 = r.get({
      facet: 'term'
    });
    var p2 = r.get({
      facet: 'place'
    });
    var p3 = r.get({
      facet: 'person'
    });
    return $q.all({
      topics: p1,
      places: p2,
      people: p3
    });
  }
]);

app.controller('browseController', function($scope, BrowseService) {

  $scope.browseOrder = '_value';
  $scope.browseDirection = '';
  $scope.textFilter = '';
  $scope.people = [];
  $scope.places = [];
  $scope.topics = [];

  BrowseService.then(function(data) {
    $scope.topics = data.topics;
  });
});
```

The following was successful before returning `$q.all()` from the factory:

```
Browse.get({
    facet: 'term'
  }, function(data) {
    $scope.topics = data['values-response']['distinct-value'];
  });

<button data-ng-repeat="topic in topics | filter:textFilter | orderBy:browseOrder:browseDirection as resultsTopics" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is $scope.topics initialized as an empty array? What I'm getting at is that angular may be attempting to render when the variable isn't defined and then not updating when the variable is defined. Another way would be to ng-if="topics" on your ng-repeat element, then you know if angular never got the updated the value of the variable.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I accidentally cut that out when simplifying the code. $scope.topics is initialized as an empty array in the controller before calling then() on BrowseService. I edited the question to include it, thanks.

Comment: not sure you can pass object to `$q.all()` that isn't a promise, have always passed promise argments themselves, then pull the data from `.then`

Comment: Right but `$q.all` accepts an array or object of promises, and that's what I'm passing. `.then` performs the resolution, and I can see the data I want in the console, but I get "undefined" when I try to assign it to a $scope variable.

Comment: The crux of the problem is, in both cases I am seeing the same data in the console, but in one case I can assign its ["distinct-value"] array to the $scope, and in the other case I cannot. Therein lies the mystery....

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between success callback parameters of `.get/.post` and `.then`. In `.then` function(result){} `result.data` is similar to `result` in `.get/.post`

Try

```
 BrowseService.then(function(results) {
     $scope.topics = results.data.topics;
     $scope.$apply();
 });
```

Also not sure its typo or you missed in `.get` you used

```
 $scope.topics = data['values-response']['distinct-value'];
```

and in `.then`

```
 $scope.topics = data.topics['values-response']['distinct-value'];
```

check you added `topics` property in response

Comment: don't use `$scope.$apply` within `then` ... will create digest in progress error

Comment: In the second case, I used $q.all() to combine 3 promises--I want 1 promise that resolves only after all 3 are resolved (yet I plan to use angular-promise-tracker so I may not want that after all, but the view depends on all 3 resource actions being successful so I thought maybe it made sense to combine them), so I specified the index by label, whereas in the other case I was performing 3 resource class get() calls in succession (I only showed the one for "topics" to keep the snippet simple.).

Comment: thanks, but I'm afraid that results in error "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'results.data.topics')", perhaps because I didn't do $scope.apply() but @charlietfl advises against doing that.

Comment: Yes, your approach for using `$q.all` is correct. But still is it data.topics or data itself is topic, this is not clear? Can you update your exact code

Comment: console.dir(data) inside your then to see exactly what the data looks like, then you can determine if what @vinayakj is suggesting is true.

Comment: console.log(data) returns what you see at the beginning of the posted question. When using $resource.get().then() I can access that distinct-value array using data['values-response']['distinct-value'], but in the case of using the service to return the combined promises, using then() on the service returns the exact same result using console.log(data.topics), but data.topics['values-response']['distinct-value'] does not work, I get "undefined" when I try to access it, even though I can see the array and the values I want in the console. Same object, but in the other case I can't get the data.

Comment: then there is no property `topics` on data so you would get undefined no wonder

Comment: No, there is. That's why in the second case, data.topics is returning the same information I want, as data does in the first case. Please look at the first "code" in the post--data.topics is returning that object.

Comment: Given that data.topics returns that object, why doesn't data.topics['values-response']['distinct-value'] return the array that you see in that object?